# Query on Triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

**Created One Trigger** in Oracle..

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER student_after_insert
  2  AFTER INSERT
  3  ON student
  4  FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     @hello.pl
  9  END student_after_insert;
 10  /
```

**Contents of hello.pl** are:-

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello world');
END;
```

And.. the result is pretty good, as the content of hello.pl is displayed on screen while inserting a record..

Now, the query is -- When i change the content of the hello.pl file, after exiting from oracle, and then logging again, It doesn't shows the updated contents, instead it shows the previous content..

I noticed that, if i drop the trigger and create it again, then it is working fine.. Why is it happening so.. And what is the solution to this problem..

Comment: You want to maintain your PL/SQL *outside* the database?

Comment: Yes... I want to maintain the PL/SQL code outside the database.. Also, if the pl/sql code is changed, then it should reflect it in the trigger itself.. Dynamic Workingg..

Comment: Well, *even if there were a way for* code outside of the database, the code must be compiled before it is executed, you won't get around that. Additionaly, with "external code", you must bear in mind that such code is not backed up. So, if you have to restore the database, you will also have to restore the "dynamic" trigger. Lastly, with "dynamic" triggers, you cannot use `all_errors` to see if there are invalid objects.

Comment: Well That is okk.. but i should know first of all, that how can i create these dynamic codes, Then only after i will look into the drawbacks of the same..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Triggers Query..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862664/oracle-triggers-query)

Answer (score 6):

It happens because the `@` works much like the `#include` in a c/c++ preprocessor, that is, `SQL*Plus` inserts the content of the file `hellp.pl` at *compile time*.

If you want to output the content of a file when the trigger is fired, you might want to look into `utl_file`.

But it's probably easier for you to create a package similar to

```
create or replace package trigger_content as 
  text varchar2(100); 
end;
/
```

You can then dynamically alter the value of text:

```
 exec trigger_content.text := 'hello world';
```

and print the value of text with

```
dbms_output.put_line(trigger_content.text);
```

However, the latter "solution" doesn't work across sessions.

Comment: Isn't There any other way,, to make this work dynamically.. Because my hello.pl file, will not only contain a hello world text,, but it will contain the series of sql statement, and etc..

Comment: I have heard, their is smthing called External Triggers, will it work for this i.e. making it dynamic..

Answer (score 0):

@hello.pl simply includes the text of hello.pl in the body of the CREATE...TRIGGER command. There is no link from Oracle to the file.

Note that, in the general case, the Oracle server is on another machine and has no access to the contents of your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Look into EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and DBMS_SQL for dynamic coding.